# pdf generation using phpexcel in windows

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, phpexcel

i am generating pdf and excel report using phpexcel library.
Everything works fine in Ubuntu system but in windows system the pdf file is not generated only the excel file is made.(Blank pdf is generated).
Is there a memory constraint in php in windows which is not allowing the pdf to be generated...if so what is the solution?

Comment: Double check with [PHPExcel's System Requirements](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements) & your PHP config.

Comment: How should we say what the difference is on your systems? You do not give any information... I suggest first you take a look in to the log files to check if any errors are spit out. You should not try to _guess_ what the problem might be. Look at the log file instead.

Comment: i have say 12 records in the database and if i generate report for 3 records ,the report is generated and if the no. of records is more than 3 ,a blank pdf is generated even though the excel file is made properly..@ShivanRaptor @arkascha

Comment: Fine, and: _did_ you check the log file or not?

Comment: yes...no error is there

Comment: Does PHPExcel successfully generate HTML if you use the HTML Writer? Which PDF rendering engine are you using?

Comment: PHPExcel successfully generates the excel file but not the pdf

Comment: Can you try posting your code. May be that will help us to debug

Comment: i changed the library from phpexcel to fpdf ...and the reports are getting generated...thanx all:)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this lines in your code

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Please take a look at this link.
May be this can help you..

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/429280

Comment: and also try replacing `EXCEL2007` by `PDF`

Comment: yes...as i had said earlier.... i have say 12 records in the database and if i generate report for 3 records ,the report is generated and if the no. of records is more than 3 ,a blank pdf is generated even though the excel file is made properly.